# How do I escape Special Characters in Solr's Schema.xml file

Tags: solr

How do I replace the special character (/) in the Schema.xml file of solr? I already am replacing the special characters(_ and -) with " " using the **solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory**.

Or can it be escaped automatically by configuration without the user having to enter the escape character() at the time of querying?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "user", do you mean someone using an application that then queries Solr, or do you mean they will be directly querying Solr?

Comment: Yes. "user" here refers to someone querying the Solr. But I do not want to enter the escape character \ at the time of querying. I want it to be configured so that the user need not enter \ before the character he wants to escape(/)